# Give a function that satisfies the following criteria.

Tags: calculus

The problem I am trying to solve is: Give an example of a function whose graph is increasing on $(0,\infty)$ and concave down on $(0,\infty)$ and which passes through the points $(1,1)$ and $(2,3)$.

I could not recall a general approach to a question like this, so I used the trial-and-error method. Some possible parent functions that came to mind were $f(x)=\ln(x), f(x)=-\dfrac{1}{x}$, and the piecewise function $f(x)= \begin{cases} 5 & \text{ if } x=0 \\ \sqrt{x} & \text{ if } x>0 \end{cases}$. All of these functions are increasing and concave down on $(0,\infty)$.

However. when I tried to manipulate these functions to satisfy the points $(1,1)$ and $(2,3)$, I was unsuccessful in coming up with the exact function. I considered finding the slope between these two points, but that would lead to a linear function which has zero concavity.

Any suggestions as to how to proceed with this problem are appreciated.

Comment: Hint I haven't tried. Look at $a\sqrt{x} + b$ and write two equations that allow you to solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: $-\frac1x$, $\sqrt x$, $\log x$, $\arctan x$, etc. are all monotonically increasing on an interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the function $ f $ defined by
$$f(x)=a - \frac bx$$

with
$$f(1)=a - b =1$$
and
$$f(2)=a - \frac b2 =3$$

to find that
$$f(x)=5-\frac 4x$$
is defined at $ (0,+\infty) $ and satisfies the desired conditions.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm struggling to understand the intuition behind your approach. Specifically, where does $f(x)=a-\frac{b}{x}$ come from? The rest makes sense.

Comment: You tried the function $-1/x$. this is a kind of translation and homothetie of it.

Comment: I get it now. It's like some sort of general form. Thanks!